# Query for pages of a specific type on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to have something like http://fanpagelist.com/category/musicians/ in my web app.

Basically I need to allow users to search through Facebook pages of musician/band category and sort by number of fans.

The closest I got was with this FB Graph API call:

```
search?q=musician&type=page&limit=25&after=MjQZD&fields=name,fan_count,category
```

But that is searching for pages that have 'musician' in the name, not in the category field.

Any idea? It must be possible since fanpagelist can do it...

Comment: There is no way to filter the results from that search endpoint directly. You will need to filter the results on your end.

Comment: @CBroe you mean sort results? That's fine, I can sort them after, but how do I only get the pages of a specific category? I can't (don't think it's even possible) get all pages on Facebook and then filter by category ...

Comment: No, I meant filter. And you won’t get “all” pages anyway. API search is rudimentary at best, plus results are always tailored to the specific user.

Comment: So you're basically saying that it's not possible? :)

Comment: @CBroe, you're right, that doesn't seem to be possible. If you put your comments as answers, I'm happy to accept that answer ... might help others in the future. Otherwise I'll add your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to filter the results from that search endpoint directly.

You are limited to the options described under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search, and that basically means you can search by name, but nothing else.

So you will need to filter the results on your end.